# Параллельное выполнение скриптов PHP

Tags: ajax, php, kohana, mysql

Здравствуйте. Делаю функцию импорта содержимого .csv файла в базу данных MySQL. Записей более 40 000 плюс надо проверять на дубликаты. Никакими усилиями не удалось запихнуть время работы в разумные 30 секунд. Решил запускать в фоне с помощью AJAX запроса. А другим AJAX-ом время от времени проверять статус выполнения.

Первый скрипт циклически переписывает файл в базу и записывает текущее значение в переменную $_SESSION['import'].

```
public function action_importcore() {

    $auth = Auth::instance();
    if ($auth->logged_in()) {
        if (isset($_GET['file'])and(isset($_GET['group']))) {
            $filename = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bases/'.$_GET['file'];
            $group = ORM::factory('group', $_GET['group']);
            $_SESSION['fullimport'] = filesize($filename);
            $fp = fopen($filename, 'r');
            $colum = fgetcsv($fp, 255, ';');
            set_time_limit(0);
            while ($dt = fgetcsv($fp, 255, ';')) {
                $person = ORM::factory('person', array($colum[1] => $dt[1]));
                if ($person->loaded()) {
                    if (!$person->has('group', $group->id))
                        $person->add('group', $group);
                } else {
                    $person->set($colum[1], $dt[1])->set($colum[0], $dt[0])->save();
                    $person->add('group', ORM::factory('group', $group));
                }
                $_SESSION['import'] = ftell($fp);
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->redirect('/');
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->redirect('/');
    }

}
```

Второй считывает значение $_SESSION['import'], считает процент и отдает AJAX-у.

```
public function action_importping() {

    $auth = Auth::instance();
    if ($auth->logged_in()) {
        if (isset($_SESSION['import'])and(isset($_SESSION['fullimport']))) {
            echo round($_SESSION['import']/$_SESSION['fullimport']*100);
        } else {
            echo 50;
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->redirect('/');
    }

}
```

Проблема в том что во время выполнения первого скрипта второй не отвечает. Вообще никакой скрипт не отвечает! Веб-сервер (кстати Apache 2.2.22 под Windows) отдает картинки и статические страницы, но виснет при запросе к любому .php скрипту. Как только первый скрипт завершает работу, все остальные могут запускаться.

Помогите разобраться в чем причина?

Comment: Попробуйте с нескольких клиентов открыть файл. Также с помощью curl (выходит, что сервер будет запрашивать сам себя, ну да и ладно) - я могу сделать сразу несколько подключений к одному скрипту, не дожидаясь ответа (таймаут выставить). Но попахивает костылем.

Comment: С других компьютеров та же ситуация.

Comment: А если просто увеличить таймаут php?

Comment: Поставил set_time_limit(400); Но по прежнему

Comment: Странно то, что виснет всё. На данную тему соображений никаких нет, вам придется дождаться другого участника. Как еще один вариант: разбить выполнение на несколько частей. Т.е. разбить сам файл на несколько частей.

Comment: 40 тысяч - это фигня, обработка должна укладываться секунд в 10 на стандартном хостинге. Но раз есть проблемы с временным лимитом - обрывайте работу скрипта после каждых n обработанных строк и запускайте заново.

Кроме того, насколько я помню, сессия записывается в файл только тогда, когда скрипт свою работу завершит. Т.е. в Вашем случае, пока первый скрипт работает, второй не имеет доступа к сессси, либо как минимум не видит изменений переменной `$_SESSION['import']`.

Comment: Равнодушный, 40 тысяч - это фигня, обработка должна укладываться секунд в 10 - как? Скрипт что я выложил запихивал в базу 42 тысячи строк чуть больше часа.

Comment: @temoffey всё еще зависит от сервера.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в сессии: при запуске скрипта, где сессия используется, скрипт лочит файл сессии. Следующий, соответственно, ждет разблокировки, потом запускается.

Вариант примерно такой:

- создаем табличку `[ ключ (session_id); значение (`$import`) ]`
- в скрипте импорта сделать так

  ```
  <?
    session_start();
    define('SID', session_id());
    session_write_close(); // имеем на руках session_id и закрытую сессию
  ?>
  ```
- в процессе импорта вставлять в табличку пару `(SID, $import)`
- в скрипте проверки соотв-но вытаскивать значение (в нем сессию можно не закрывать, он быстрый)

Вариант проще и "наколенный"

```
  <?
    // import.php
    session_start();
    define('SID', session_id());
    session_write_close();
    // code, code etc
    file_put_contents(SID.'.data', $import)
  ?>
  <?
    // check.php
    session_start();
    $import = (int) @file_get_contents(session_id().'.data');
  ?>
```

Comment: Жесть... Разве не проще ввести некий новый временный файл статуса, зачем так издеваться над бедной сессией?

Comment: @Равнодушный, а второй вариант - это что?)

Comment: Ну да, не то прочитал...)